# Django ORM - Выборка по неизвестному заранее количеству возможных значений

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, orm

Я очень плох в общении с ORM, так что могу упускать простое решение.

У меня есть модель с различными данными и формой поиска для нее где через мультилист можно выбрать варианты значения, например сок: яблочный, апельсиновый, морковный. Пользователь может выбрать 1, 3 или ни одного варианта. Таких элементов в форме до 5шт и не все они могут иметь значение.

В сети есть разные варианты и мое внимание привлекло:

```
from django.db.models import Q
model.objects.filter(Q(juice='яблочный') | Q(juice='апельсиновый'))
```

и

```
d = dict(request.GET)
model.objects.filter(**d)
```

Но ни один из них не подходит к моему случая и я ожидаю, что ORM соберет сам запрос с OR по представленному списку/словарю, но не могу пока понять как именно его заставить сгенерировать такой запрос не зная заранее кол-во переменных:

```
SELECT * FROM js WHERE 1=1 OR ... OR ... OR ...
```

До этого поста я пытался собирать список и откидывать лишние записи в цикле по условию, но такое решение мне кажется тяжелым и неуклюжим, может быть есть что-то иное?

*Увы, я вынужден использовать именно ORM.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это было решением моей проблемы:

```
from django.db.models import Q 
q_objects = Q()
for t in dict(request.GET)['operator']:
    q_objects |= Q(operator__contains=t)

search_data = search_data.filter(q_objects)
```

Это решение упоминается тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076822/django-dynamically-filtering-with-q-objects

Надеюсь, что вам это поможет так же как и мне.